# What is the Maven dependency for org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpMethods for a Spring Boot app?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, maven-dependency

What dependency should I add for `org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpMethods` to be added to my Spring boot project? I have tried these but none of these seem to be working...

```
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-http 
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient
```

Also, I could not find the dependency on Google search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`org.apache.camel.component.http.HttpMethods` can be found in `org.apache.camel:camel-http` artifact.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-http</artifactId>
  <version>2.22.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm not sure why you are saying it's not there:

```
$ zipinfo -1 camel-http-2.22.1.jar | grep HttpMethods
org/apache/camel/component/http/HttpMethods.class
```

Comment: The Maven build was still running in the background when I added that dependency. My mistake. This worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add these dependencies to your project :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  <version>${camel.version}</version> <!-- the camel version -->
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-http-starter</artifactId>
  <version>${camel.version}</version> <!-- the camel version -->
</dependency>
```